# Why won't my side nav extend the length of the body/wrapper?

Tags: html, css

I feel like I've tried every combination of min-height: 100%, height: 100%, height: auto !important, etc etc. I have a wrapper that wraps my entire body code, and a nav within the body code (but outside of 'main') that is supposed to run vertical along the side.

```css
body {
 background-color: #f8f8f8;
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 height: 100%;
}


main {
 width: 75%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(4, 78, 28, .5);
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-right: 5%;
 float:right;
 background-color: blue;
}

#content {
 height: 100%;
 background-color: red;
 
}


#wrapper {
 margin: auto;
 width: 90%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
 background-color: green;
 
}

nav {
 float: left;
 width: 15%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #a40204;
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<body>
<header>
<img src="images/banner.jpg"/>
</header>

<hr id="hr">

<nav>

<!-- JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT MENU FROM GOOTEACH-->

<ul class="goo-collapsible goo-coll-stacked">
  <li><a href='#'> Home</a></li>
  <li class='dropdown'><a class='' href='#'>About</a>
         <ul>
             <li ><a href='#'>Who is Jim?</a></li>
                <li ><a href='#'>The history of the bagpipes</a></li>
                
   </ul>
  </li>
        <li><a href='#'> Gallery</a></li>  
        <li><a href='#'> Contact</a></li>                
 </ul>
</nav>
 
<main>
<div id="content">
<img src="images/indexmain.jpg" alt="Bagpiper on a hill" width="40%"/>
<h1>Bagpipes for parties, corporate events, weddings, and more!</h1>
<p>
A BUNCH OF TEXT HERE
</p>
<h2>The Sounds of Scotland</h2>
<p>Jim Miller has played for weddings, parades, parties, and funerals. Listen to two popular
bagpiping songs, The Conundrum and Green Monster. 
<h3>Listen to: The Conundrum</h3>
<audio controls="controls" title="Listen to: The Conundrum March">
 <source src="conundrum.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 <source src="conundrum.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
 <a href="conundrum.mp3">Download The Conundrum March</a> (MP3)
</audio>
<br/>
<h3>Listen to: Green Monster</h3>
<audio controls="controls" title="Listen to: Green Monster">
 <source src="greenmonster.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 <source src="greenmonster.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
 <a href="greenmonster.mp3">Download Green Monster</a> (MP3)
</audio> 
</div>
</main>
<div class="clear">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issues in the past as well. With HTML & CSS everything will take up the width at 100% because that is defined. The height can be anything. So we have to define that. I changed a couple things:

body{
height: 1000px <- I set this so it knows how big to be and everything inside it has a reference point of what 100% means. 
}

main{
I removed padding bottom and top to allow it to be even. If you are trying to push the text toward the center there are better ways to do this. 
}

nav{
height:100% I set this to 100% to match it with the bottom of the main. 
}

For the browser the height is basically infinite. What is 100% of infinite? So it just allows divs to only take up the space around the content.

I hope this is what you were going for. If not or need something else please let me know. :)

My changes in code form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
body {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 1000px;
}


main {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(4, 78, 28, .5);
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    float:right;
    background-color: blue;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;

}


#wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    background-color: green;

}

nav {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #a40204;
    margin-top: 0;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<img src="images/banner.jpg"/>
</header>

<hr id="hr">

<nav>

<!-- JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT MENU FROM GOOTEACH-->

<ul class="goo-collapsible goo-coll-stacked">
        <li><a href='#'> Home</a></li>
        <li class='dropdown'><a class='' href='#'>About</a>
            <ul>
                <li ><a href='#'>Who is Jim?</a></li>
                <li ><a href='#'>The history of the bagpipes</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'> Gallery</a></li>  
        <li><a href='#'> Contact</a></li>                
    </ul>
</nav>

<main>
<div id="content">
<img src="images/indexmain.jpg" alt="Bagpiper on a hill" width="40%"/>
<h1>Bagpipes for parties, corporate events, weddings, and more!</h1>
<p>
A BUNCH OF TEXT HERE
</p>
<h2>The Sounds of Scotland</h2>
<p>Jim Miller has played for weddings, parades, parties, and funerals. Listen to two popular
bagpiping songs, The Conundrum and Green Monster. 
<h3>Listen to: The Conundrum</h3>
<audio controls="controls" title="Listen to: The Conundrum March">
    <source src="conundrum.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="conundrum.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <a href="conundrum.mp3">Download The Conundrum March</a> (MP3)
</audio>
<br/>
<h3>Listen to: Green Monster</h3>
<audio controls="controls" title="Listen to: Green Monster">
    <source src="greenmonster.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="greenmonster.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <a href="greenmonster.mp3">Download Green Monster</a> (MP3)
</audio>    
</div>
</main>
<div class="clear">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```